Android 14 - Unable to enable SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission
Application which fires local notifications for Users in Android 14 the SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission needs to be explicitly granted by Users otherwise a security exception is now thrown.
I am initiating a request for the permission to the User and the modal is successfully popping but the option to toggle the permission on / off is greyed out as seen in the attached screen capture?

I have added the permission in the Android manifest and am initiating the request with the below code

  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Check if the app can schedule exact alarms
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S && !alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()) {
            // If not, request the SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivity(intent);
        }   
    }


In Android 14, the behavior of requesting the SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission has changed, and users may see the option to toggle the permission greyed out. This is usually because of the following reasons:

App’s Target SDK Version
App’s Battery Optimization Settings
Device Manufacturer's Restrictions: Some OEMs (Original Equipment Manufacturers) may have their own customizations or restrictions that can affect how permissions like SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM are granted. Ensure that no additional settings are needed from the device’s specific settings.

Possible solution:
1. Guide Users to Manually Enable the Permission:
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S && !alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()) {
            // Request permission
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            // Guide the user to manually enable it if the toggle is greyed out
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable the SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission in the device settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

2. Exclude the App from Battery Optimization:
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);


The application is not subject to battery optimization and navigating users to where they can enable to setting is what Im currently trying its just the option is greyed out when the settings are displayed

App targets SDK 33 which should be fine according to the docs
